# Blazor WebAssembly - Dispose not firing on browser close

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have blazor app running WASM (not server) on .NET 5, version 5.0.3. I would like to be able to detect when a user navigates away from the site or closes the browser. The dispose only seems to fire when navigating within the app itself (i.e. the page or control is disposed due to a navigation).

Here is my page markup, I have also tried implementing IAsyncDisposable with the same result:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IHubManager HubManager
@implements IDisposable

<Tabs />


@code{

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _ = HubManager.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
```

According to some of the posts I have read here, this approach works when using the server version of blazor, can anyone tell me if there is another approach I need to use with WASM?

The goal is to be able to close / dispose a connection to my signalR hub at the point the user leaves the site.

Comment: Are you worried the server won't clean up resources associated with the connection when the client abruptly terminates the connection?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync to maintain a list of users as per the below article, OnDisconnectedAsync doesnt fire in the event of the browser closing (something else I expected to happen but another discussion)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: I do not observe that behavior.  In fact, I never call `DisposeAsync` on my instance of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection` and yet `OnDisconnectedAsync` is in fact called on the server when I close the browser.  (and yes, I am using WASM)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you determining that it is not being called?  If you are running with the debugger, and you close the browser that Visual Studio had itself started, it will terminate the application (server), so any breakpoints you have set in `OnDisconnectedAsync` might go undetected.

Comment: Ok that's interesting, I have my hub connection in an IDisposable HubManager (my own code) and the HubManager is injected into the pages / controls as required. The HubManager dispose closes down the connection. Maybe I need to look at that more closely. Thank you, I'll update here with my findings.

Comment: "how are you determining that it is not being called" I am debugging, so when navigating away everything continues to run. I've also tried opening multiple tabs, which creates multiple connections, and then closing all but one so that the server app continues to run.

Comment: @KirkWoll I have added some extra logging published to an azure web app, and I'm seeing the behaviour exactly as you described. The disconnect is firing about a minute after the browser is closed or the user navigates away. I haven't been able to replicate locally while debugging, possibly just a limitation. It would still be useful to perform the disconnect on demand so that I have a real-time view of user disconnects, so I think the original question is still valid. I really appreciate the advice, its going to get me moving again. Thank you!

Comment: The debugger is the browser you already closed.  VS isn't attaching an external debugger to the browser, it's using the browser's debugging infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't hit a breakpoint while debugging is mentioned in the Blazor WebAssembly documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio):

> For now, you can't:
>
> - Break on unhandled exceptions.
> - Hit breakpoints during app startup before the debug proxy is running. This includes breakpoints in Program.cs and breakpoints in the OnInitialized{Async} lifecycle methods of components that are loaded by the first page requested from the app.
> - Debug in non-local scenarios (for example, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) or Visual Studio Codespaces).
> - Automatically rebuild the backend Server app of a hosted Blazor WebAssembly solution during debugging, for example by running the app with dotnet watch run.

I guess component disposal is one of those scenarios even though it is not mentioned.

**In these scenarios, what I do is just use the logger to log some lines or add some `Console.WriteLine(...)` and use the F12 tool console in the browser to see whether they were hit.**

NOTE: This works for components while navigating around the entire Blazor site.  As other members indicate, if you are closing the browser window, you won't be able to see anything in the F12 Tool as it is automatically closed.

Comment: How will you do that when the *browser* closes? That's why breakpoints can't be hit - the debugger itself, ie the browser, is closing

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about that but I absolutely agree because the F12 tool closes automatically with it, thanks!  However the `Dispose()` is also called for components when you, for example, use the `NavLink` to navigate to another component or page and, in this case, the log can be seen in the console.